# Binomial heap in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, queue, heap

I have this implementation of a binomial heap providing insert, decrease-key and extract in logarithmic time.

**MinPriorityQueue.java**:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.ds;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for the various minimum-priority queue
 * data structures.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @param <E> the type of elements stored by the implementation.
 * @param <P> the type of the priority keys.
 * @version 1.6
 */
public abstract class MinPriorityQueue<E, P extends Comparable<? super P>> {

    /**
     * Adds <code>element</code> and assigns to it the priority 
     * <code>priority</code>.
     * 
     * @param element  the element to store.
     * @param priority the priority of the element.
     */
    public abstract void add(final E element, final P priority);

    /**
     * Decreases the priority of the element <code>element</code> if it is 
     * present. If the element is not in this heap, or new priority does not
     * improve the current priority, does nothing.
     * 
     * @param element     the element whose priority to decrease.
     * @param newPriority the new priority of <code>element</code>.
     */
    public abstract void decreasePriority(final E element, final P newPriority);

    /**
     * Extracts the element with the lowest priority.
     * 
     * @return the element with the lowest priority.
     * 
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if the heap is empty.
     */
    public abstract E extractMinimum();

    /**
     * Returns but does not remove the minimum element.
     * 
     * @return the minimum element. 
     */
    public abstract E min();

    /**
     * Returns the amount of elements in the heap.
     * 
     * @return the amount of elements in the heap. 
     */
    public abstract int size();

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> it this heap is empty. <code>false</code> 
     * otherwise.
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> or <code>false</code>.
     */
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * Removes all elements from this heap.
     */
    public abstract void clear();

    /**
     * Spawns another empty heap with the same implementation.
     * 
     * @return another empty heap.
     */
    public abstract MinPriorityQueue<E, P> spawn();

    /**
     * Returns a string indicating the actual implementation type.
     * 
     * @return a string indicating implementation type.
     */
    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

**BinomialHeap.java**:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.ds.support;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.ds.MinPriorityQueue;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements binomial heap.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <E> the element type.
 * @param <P> the type of priority keys.
 */
public class BinomialHeap<E, P extends Comparable<? super P>>
extends MinPriorityQueue<E, P> {

    /**
     * The default map capacity.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAP_CAPACITY = 1 << 10;

    /**
     * This class implements a binomial tree in a binomial heap.
     * 
     * @param <E> the element type.
     * @param <P> the type of priority keys.
     */
    private static final class BinomialTree<E, P> {

        /**
         * The actual element of this node.
         */
        E element;

        /**
         * The priority key of this node.
         */
        P priority;

        /**
         * The parent node.
         */
        BinomialTree<E, P> parent;

        /**
         * Immediate sibling of this node to the right.
         */
        BinomialTree<E, P> sibling;

        /**
         * The leftmost child of this node.
         */
        BinomialTree<E, P> child;

        /**
         * The amount of children of this node.
         */
        int degree;

        /**
         * Constructs a new node and initialize it with mandatory data.
         * 
         * @param element  the element to store in this node.
         * @param priority the priority of the element stored.
         */
        BinomialTree(E element, P priority) {
            this.element = element;
            this.priority = priority;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the amount of elements in this binomial heap.
     */
    private int size;

    /**
     * Points to the leftmost node in the root list of this heap.
     */
    private BinomialTree<E, P> head;

    /**
     * Caches the binomial tree with the least priority key.
     */
    private BinomialTree<E, P> minimumTree;

    /**
     * Maps each element in the heap to its respective node.
     */
    private final Map<E, BinomialTree<E, P>> map;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code BinomialHeap} with default settings.
     */
    public BinomialHeap() {
        this(DEFAULT_MAP_CAPACITY);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code BinomialHeap} using <code>mapCapacity</code> as 
     * the initial capacity for the underlying map.
     * 
     * @param mapCapacity the initial map capacity.
     */
    public BinomialHeap(final int mapCapacity) {
        this.map = new HashMap<>(mapCapacity);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binomial heap with only one element. Used for the sake of 
     * <code>add</code>-operation, which simply unites the current heap with the
     * one created by this constructor.
     * 
     * @param element the application-specific satellite data.
     * @param priority the priority of <code>element</code>.
     */
    private BinomialHeap(final E element, final P priority) {
        BinomialTree<E, P> tree = new BinomialTree<>(element, priority);
        head = tree;
        minimumTree = tree;
        size = 1;
        map = null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void add(E element, P priority) {
        if (map.containsKey(element)) {
            // element already in this heap, use decreaseKey instead.
            return;
        }

        BinomialHeap<E, P> h = new BinomialHeap<>(element, priority);

        if (size == 0) {
            this.head = h.head;
            this.minimumTree = h.head;
            this.map.put(element, this.head);
            this.size = 1;
        } else {
            heapUnion(h.head);
            this.map.put(element, h.head);
            this.size++;

            if (minimumTree.priority.compareTo(h.minimumTree.priority) > 0) {
                minimumTree = h.minimumTree;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void decreasePriority(E element, P newPriority) {
        if (!map.containsKey(element)) {
            // No element here.
            return;
        } 

        BinomialTree<E, P> target = map.get(element);

        if (target.priority.compareTo(newPriority) <= 0) {
            // The priority key of element won't improve.
            return;
        }

        final E saveElement = target.element;

        BinomialTree<E, P> p = target.parent;
        BinomialTree<E, P> x = target;

        while (p != null && newPriority.compareTo(p.priority) < 0) {
            x.priority = p.priority;
            x.element = p.element;

            // Advance one level up.
            x = p;
            p = p.parent;
        }

        x.element = saveElement;
        x.priority = newPriority;

        if (minimumTree.priority.compareTo(x.priority) > 0) {
            minimumTree = x;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public E extractMinimum() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "Reading from an empty binomial heap.");
        }

        BinomialTree<E, P> x = head;
        BinomialTree<E, P> prevx = null;
        BinomialTree<E, P> best = x;
        BinomialTree<E, P> bestprev = null;
        P minPriorityKey = x.priority;

        // Find the tree T with the least priority element and the tree 
        // preceding T.
        while (x != null) {
            if (minPriorityKey.compareTo(x.priority) > 0) {
                minPriorityKey = x.priority;
                best = x;
                bestprev = prevx;
            }

            prevx = x;
            x = x.sibling;
        }

        // Remove from root list the tree with the least priority root.
        if (bestprev == null) {
            head = best.sibling;
        } else {
            bestprev.sibling = best.sibling;
        }

        // Unite this heap with the reversed list of children of the tree whose
        // root contained the extracted element.
        heapUnion(reverseRootList(best.child));

        // Update the cached minimum tree.
        if (--size > 0) {
            BinomialTree<E, P> minTree = head;
            BinomialTree<E, P> t = head.sibling;
            P minPriority = head.priority;

            while (t != null) {
                if (minPriority.compareTo(t.priority) > 0) {
                    minPriority = t.priority;
                    minTree = t;
                }

                t = t.sibling;
            }

            minimumTree = minTree;
        }

        return best.element;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public E min() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Reading from an empty heap.");
        }

        return minimumTree.element;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.head = null;
        this.map.clear();
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public MinPriorityQueue<E, P> spawn() {
       return new BinomialHeap<>();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BinomialHeap";
    }

    /**
     * Makes <code>y</code> a leftmost child of <code>z</code>.
     * 
     * @param y the node to become a child of <code>z</code>.
     * @param z the node to become a parent of <code>y</code>.
     */
    private void link(final BinomialTree<E, P> child, 
                      final BinomialTree<E, P> parent) {
        child.parent = parent;
        child.sibling = parent.child;
        parent.child = child;
        parent.degree++;
    }

    /**
     * Merges the root lists of this heap and <code>other</code>.
     * 
     * @param other another binomial heap whose root list to merge.
     * 
     * @return the head of the merged root list. 
     */
    private BinomialTree<E, P> mergeRoots(final BinomialTree<E, P> other) {
        BinomialTree<E, P> a = head;
        BinomialTree<E, P> b = other;

        if (a == null) {
            return b;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return a;
        }

        BinomialTree<E, P> rootListHead;
        BinomialTree<E, P> rootListTail;

        // Initialize rootListHead and rootListTail.
        if (a.degree < b.degree) {
            rootListHead = a;
            rootListTail = a;
            a = a.sibling;
        } else {
            rootListHead = b;
            rootListTail = b;
            b = b.sibling;
        }

        while (a != null && b != null) {
            if (a.degree < b.degree) {
                rootListTail.sibling = a;
                rootListTail = a;
                a = a.sibling;
            } else {
                rootListTail.sibling = b;
                rootListTail = b;
                b = b.sibling;
            }
        }

        if (a != null) {
            // Just append the rest.
            rootListTail.sibling = a;
        } else {
            // Just append the rest.
            rootListTail.sibling = b;
        }

        return rootListHead;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the root list as to facilitate the <code>extractMinimum</code>.
     * Sets the parent references to <code>null</code> also.
     * 
     * @param first the head node of the root list to reverse.
     * 
     * @return the reversed root list. 
     */
    private BinomialTree<E, P> reverseRootList(final BinomialTree<E, P> first) {
        BinomialTree<E, P> tmp = first; // This is the cursor over the list.
        BinomialTree<E, P> tmpnext;
        BinomialTree<E, P> newHead = null;

        while (tmp != null) {
            tmpnext = tmp.sibling;
            tmp.sibling = newHead;
            newHead = tmp;
            tmp = tmpnext;
        }

        return newHead;
    }

    /**
     * Unites this heap with <code>other</code>. This subroutine is used in both
     * <code>add</code> and <code>extractMinimum</code>.
     * 
     * @param other the heap to unite with this heap. 
     */
    private void heapUnion(final BinomialTree<E, P> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return;
        }

        BinomialTree<E, P> t = mergeRoots(other);
        BinomialTree<E, P> prev = null;
        BinomialTree<E, P> x = t;
        BinomialTree<E, P> next = x.sibling;

        while (next != null) {
            if ((x.degree != next.degree)
                    || (next.sibling != null 
                    && next.sibling.degree == x.degree)) {
                prev = x;
                x = next;
            } else if (x.priority.compareTo(next.priority) <= 0) {
                x.sibling = next.sibling;
                link(next, x);
            } else {
                if (prev == null) {
                    t = next;
                } else {
                    prev.sibling = next;
                }

                link(x, next);
                x = next;
            }

            next = x.sibling;
        }

        this.head = t;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.ds;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.ds.support.BinomialHeap;

public class Demo {

    private static final int TO_LOAD = 100000;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final MinPriorityQueue<Integer, Integer> heap = new BinomialHeap<>();

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < TO_LOAD; ++i) {
            heap.add(i, i);
        }

        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("add() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = TO_LOAD / 2; i < TO_LOAD; ++i) {
            heap.decreasePriority(i, i - TO_LOAD);
        }

        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("decreasePriority() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        boolean isCorrect = true;

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < TO_LOAD - TO_LOAD / 2; ++i) {
            if (!heap.extractMinimum().equals(i + TO_LOAD / 2)) {
                isCorrect = false;
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isCorrect) {
            for (int i = 0; i < TO_LOAD / 2; ++i) {
                if (!heap.extractMinimum().equals(i)) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    isCorrect = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("extractMinimum() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        System.out.println("Is correct: " + isCorrect);
    }
}
```

**BinomialHeapTest.java**:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.ds.support;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BinomialHeapTest {

    private static final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private final BinomialHeap<Integer, Integer> heap;

    public BinomialHeapTest() {
        this.heap = new BinomialHeap<>();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initClass() {
        System.out.println("BinomialHeapTest.java, seed: " + seed);
    }

    /**
     * Clears the heap before any test.
     */
    @Before
    public void init() {
        heap.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAndExtractMinimum() {
        final int sz = 100000;
        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);

        for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
            Integer ii = rnd.nextInt();
            heap.add(ii, ii);
        }

        Integer prev = null;

        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            Integer current = heap.extractMinimum();

            if (prev != null && prev > current) {
                fail("The sequence was not monotonically increasing. " +
                     "Previous: " + prev + ", current: " + current + ".");
            }

            prev = current;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDecreasePriority() {
        for (int i = 10; i != 0; --i) {
            heap.add(i, i);
        }

        heap.decreasePriority(10, -1);

        assertEquals((Integer) 10, heap.extractMinimum());

        int i = 1;
        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            assertEquals((Integer) i, heap.extractMinimum());
            i++;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());

        final long sz = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            assertEquals(i, heap.size());
            heap.add(i, i);
        }

        assertEquals(sz, heap.size());
        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.add(0, 0);

        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.add(1, -1);

        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.extractMinimum();

        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.extractMinimum();

        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.add(100, 10);
        heap.add(10, 1);

        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());

        heap.clear();

        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testClear() {
        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());

        final int sz = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            heap.add(i, i);
            assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());
        }

        heap.clear();

        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(0, heap.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpawn() {
        heap.add(1, 2);

        BinomialHeap<Integer, Integer> heap2 = 
                (BinomialHeap<Integer, Integer>) heap.spawn();

        assertTrue(heap2 instanceof BinomialHeap);
        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());
        assertTrue(heap2.isEmpty());
    }

    /**
     * Additional test.
     */
    @Test
    public void additionalTest() {
        heap.add(2, 2);
        heap.add(1, 1);
        heap.add(3, 7);
        heap.add(4, 6);
        heap.decreasePriority(3, -1);
        heap.decreasePriority(4, 10);
        heap.add(4, -4);

        assertEquals(4, heap.size());
        assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());

        assertEquals((Integer) 3, heap.extractMinimum());
        assertEquals((Integer) 1, heap.extractMinimum());
        assertEquals((Integer) 2, heap.extractMinimum());
        assertEquals((Integer) 4, heap.extractMinimum());

        assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(0, heap.size());
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testExtractingFromEmptyThrows() {
        heap.add(10, 10);
        heap.add(1, 29);

        heap.extractMinimum();
        heap.extractMinimum();
        heap.extractMinimum();
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testPeekingEmptyHeapThrows() {
        heap.min();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMin() {
        heap.add(3, 3); // (3, 3)

        assertEquals((Integer) 3, heap.min());

        heap.add(2, 2); // (2, 2) (3, 3)

        assertEquals((Integer) 2, heap.min());

        assertEquals(2, heap.size());

        heap.decreasePriority(3, 1); // (3, 1) (2, 2)

        assertEquals((Integer) 3, heap.min());

        assertEquals(2, heap.size());

        assertEquals((Integer) 3, heap.extractMinimum()); // (2, 2)

        assertEquals(1, heap.size());

        assertEquals((Integer) 2, heap.min());

        assertEquals((Integer) 2, heap.extractMinimum());

        assertEquals(0, heap.size());

        try {
            heap.min();
            fail("BinomialHeap did not throw on being read while empty.");
        } catch (final NoSuchElementException nsee) {

        }
    }
}
```

So what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I see some issues with the interface.

`MinPriorityQueue` is an abstract class that contains no instructions.  It would be better as an interface instead.  In that case, neither `spawn()` nor `toString()` would be part of that interface.  If you wanted to support `spawn()`, then make a separate `Spawnable<T>` interface.  And your `toString()` is pointless — not only do all objects in Java support `toString()`, your implementation, which just returns `"BinomialHeap"`, is arguably less useful than the usual `BinomialHeap@56e88e24` that Java gives you.  If you hadn't declared `toString()` to be abstract, you could have gotten the default behaviour for free.

---

I find this behaviour troubling:

```
public void add(E element, P priority) {
    if (map.containsKey(element)) {
        // element already in this heap, use decreaseKey instead.
        return;
    }
    …
}
```

If someone tries to add an element that is already present, I would consider the following possible behaviours reasonable (from best to weirdest, in my opinion):

1. Add a second instance of the same element (list-like semantics).
2. Throw an exception
3. Return `false` if the element was not added because it already exists ([`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))-like semantics)
4. Reprioritize the existing entry

Silently doing nothing is not acceptable, in my opinion.

An analogous problem exists in `decreasePriority()`:

```
public void decreasePriority(E element, P newPriority) {
    if (!map.containsKey(element)) {
        // No element here.
        return;
    } 
    …
}
```

There, my expectation would be to throw an exception if no such element exists.

---

Since your `BinomialHeap` uses a map, you might as well offer a `.contains(E)` method.

Comment: I need the hash map in order to keep decreasePriority an O(log n) operation. Otherwise, I would need to traverse the entire heap to find the node containing the element, and that's O(n).